# How do I Create a Faceted Bar Graph with Different Discrete X Axis in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a bar graph which looks like the following:

[image: Graph that I would like to facet]

**Problem:** If I facet it by the same variable as the color, the x-axis has space for plotting all the bars even though I don't need them.

[image: Faceted plot with extra spaces]

**My Solution:** I used multiplot function from the Rmisc to separately make bar graphs for each partner but then a lot of individual customization is needed to make the graphs go cohesively together.

[image: Make-shift graph using Rmisc::multiplot function]

**Question:** Is there another way that I can use to get closer to plot 2 without the extra spaces for the variables that don't apply.

I'm using ggplot to plot.

Comment: Try specifying `scales = "free"` and `space = "free"` in `facet_grid()`?

Comment: scales = 'free' did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
+ facet_wrap(~variable_to_facet_by, 
             scales = 'free')
```

as part of your ggplot code and that should get you what you want.

Comment: it may not get rid of blank spots in the middle of data but it should as least trim the ends.